# changes not staged for commit with git bash

Tags: git

I've got an issue with git bash.

After modifying files I added on the staging area and then do a commit, the modifictions I made on my files aren't on the commit.
On this commit, files are on the same state that they were when i did a `git add`.
If I want to have my modifications on a commit, I have to do a `git add` just before comitting.
I'm using Intellij Idea and when I use its UI to do a commit, I don't have this issue. I'm only having this issue when I use git bash, on the terminal.

Comment: Changes made *after* `git add` aren't committed. That's just how Git works.

Comment: [Git is simpler than you think](http://nfarina.com/post/9868516270/git-is-simpler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour and by design. `git add` adds changes that will go into the next commit. If you make changes after running `git add`, those will not be in the index and so will not go into the next commit, unless you add those as well before you commit.

See [2.2 Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book) for more information about how this works.